# Override context and client classes in Azure Functions application

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I'm working on an Azure functions application, using runtime version 4.28.4.4 and targeting .NET 6.0. There is an orchestrator which starts chains of sub-orchestrations and activities. My goal is to provide some supplementary information to each element of chain without need to pass it explicitly via arguments.
Let us say I have a class "Payload" representing the supplementary data. Now I should be able to declare a trigger function with custom orchestration starter like to `[DurableClient] IDerivedOrchestrationClient starter` and start processing. It could look like this:

```
[FunctionName("Starter")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [DurableClient] IDerivedOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    Payload p = new Payload(){
        Data = "foobarbaz"
    };
    
    var id = await starter.StartNewWithPayloadAsync(nameof(MainOrchestrator), p, "orchestration argument");
    return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, id);
}
```

After that each orchestration and activity function from the chain should be able to get the payload by demand. Is there any way to do that? Not exactly as I described of course. There could be other tricks not known for me. But the main idea should be clear. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context object provided by Durable Functions. This context object allows storing and retrieving data across function invocations within the same orchestration instance. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

1. Define a class to hold your supplementary data (Payload).
2. Store the payload in the orchestration context.
3. Retrieve the payload in each orchestrator function or activity function as needed.

a quick example to do so

```
public class Payload
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class StarterFunction
{
    [FunctionName("Starter")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger log)
    {
        Payload p = new Payload()
        {
            Data = "foobarbaz"
        };

        var orchestrationInput = new
        {
            Payload = p,
            OrchestrationArgument = "orchestration argument"
        };

        var instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(MainOrchestrator), orchestrationInput);

        return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(MainOrchestrator))]
    public async Task RunOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        // Retrieve the payload from the orchestration context
        var payload = context.GetInput<Payload>();

        // Start sub-orchestrations or activities and pass the payload as needed
        // Example:
        await context.CallActivityAsync("ActivityFunction", payload);

        // Start sub-orchestrations and pass the payload as needed
        // Example:
        await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("SubOrchestratorFunction", payload);
    }

    [FunctionName("ActivityFunction")]
    public async Task RunActivity(
        [ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context)
    {
        // Retrieve the payload from the activity context
        var payload = context.GetInput<Payload>();

        // Use the payload as needed
        // Example:
        string data = payload.Data;
    }

    [FunctionName("SubOrchestratorFunction")]
    public async Task RunSubOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        // Retrieve the payload from the sub-orchestration context
        var payload = context.GetInput<Payload>();

        // Use the payload as needed
        // Example:
        string data = payload.Data;
    }
}
```

- The payload is stored in the orchestration input when starting the orchestration.
- The payload is retrieved in each orchestrator function (MainOrchestrator) and activity function (ActivityFunction, SubOrchestratorFunction) using the GetInput method provided by the IDurableOrchestrationContext or IDurableActivityContext.

Comment: That is not exactly what I'm seeking for. Sure I can send the payload through all orchestrations to activities explicitly, but the idea is to set this payload only once and then just take from context when it is needed. Not each orchestration element will read it so I'd like to keep it in context until an activity read it.

Comment: @Infarch are you able to control each suborchestrator and function? Or do you have some activities in between that you cannot control and would like to still pass from the main orchestrator and still be able to see that passed to the next inline (going through the others) so that you can use it at that point?

Comment: The answer is not answering the question. Also, there're errors in the example.

Comment: @DMadden51 I can control it but there already are hundreds of orchestrators and activities created. The Payload which I'm talking about is a new feature in a big project. Changes must be as minimal as possible, and localized in several files. That is why I'm looking for a way with minimum code. Azure functions allow to do great things, but unfortunately not everything is documented properly. Maybe a kind of DI could allow to have more control over the execution context...